# LaravelCollective create single Form Select from 2 tables combined

Tags: forms, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravelcollective

I have 2 tables, `country` and `city`:

```
table 'country'
+----+------------+
| id |    name    |
+----+------------+
|  1 | Indonesia  |
|  2 |  Malaysia  |
+----+------------+
```

`country` has many `city`, so `country_id` is the foreign key:

```
table 'city'
+----+------------+------------+
| id |      name  | country_id |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 |   Jakarta  |          1 |
|  2 |  Surabaya  |          1 |
|  3 |   Kuching  |          2 |
+----+------------+------------+
```

I would like to use [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html#drop-down-lists) to create a grouped drop-down list so that

1. `country->name` becomes label of `<optgroup>`
2. `city` is grouped by their `country` and becomes value of `<option>` in HTML `<select>`

What I need for LaravelCollective is to create array that looks like this:

```
[
    'Indonesia' => ['1' => 'Jakarta', '2' => 'Surabaya'],
    'Malaysia' => ['3' => 'Kuching']
]
```

`City::get(['name', 'country_id', 'id'])->toArray()` gave me grouped array, but not key-value paired and `country_id` is still inside the created array.

Is there a good way to do this? Do I have to use `foreach` on either `controller` or `view` with traditional HTML `<select>` instead of Laravel Collective or 2 drop-down linked with JavaScript?

Thanks~

Comment: Well, you can use ajax call instead get all cities at the first. When user select a country, you can get only this cities

Comment: I'm aware of that. But what I would like to achieve is only using single drop-down for combined country & city, not one drop-down for each of them.